# Custom setter in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, getter-setter

I'm trying to declare a custom getter of a NSDictionary but I can't get it to work.

So far I have the @property declared and the synthesize syntax.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *variableDictionary;
@synthesize variableDictionary = _variableDictionary;
```

I want to declare a setter for the dictionary that gives it some standard values.

```
-(void)setVariableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)variableDictionary {
    NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:20];
    NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:10];
    NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:5];
    NSDictionary *_variableDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", b, @"b", x, @"x", nil];
}
```

When I use the above method I get a warning unused variable, and if I remove the underscore from the NSDictionary variable definition, I get an error saying 'redefinition of variable dictionary'.

I'm not sure of the correct way to do this.

Comment: wouldn't this make your dictionary a static dictionary as whenever you try to set your dictionary it will always have the same value.. as you are not using the passed in dictionary? please someone clear my doubt.

Comment: @Ankit Srivastava makes a good point.  What are you hoping to archive with this?  If you want your dictionary property to have some default values, would it not be better to call `setVariableDictionary` in an init method for your class and pass the default values you want to the property that way?

Comment: Refer to my answer. That may help you

Answer (score 1):

_variableDictionary is already declared.

Replace

```
NSDictionary *_variableDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]
initWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", b, @"b", x, @"x", nil];
```

with

```
_variableDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", b, @"b", x, @"x", nil];
```

Comment: When I do this and try to access the '_variableDictionary' variable it returns null.

Comment: Don't know what to say, his answer is correct and it should work fine with this. Are you sure it is nil after setting it and also that you are reading the correct variable when printing this out?

Comment: Do I need to do anything extra to make the method run? When I put         NSLog(@"Value of dictionary = %@", _variableDictionary);  Inside the method there is no output.

Comment: It's as if my custom setter isn't running.  I can copy the exact code that was inside it into another method and it works perfectly.

Comment: @AFraser See my answer and you should be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom `setVarableDictionary:` setter method, when you write:

```
NSDictionary *_variableDictionary = _variableDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", b, @"b", x, @"x", nil];
```

this declares and sets value for a new local variable within the scope of your function only.  The warning message you get is because that variable is not used before it goes out of scope.

Instead of creating a local variable, you should just set the value of the ivar that underlies your property, like this:

```
_variableDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", b, @"b", x, @"x", nil];
```

Comment: When I do this my code compiles without any warnings but whenever I try to access the variable from a different method user '_variableDictionary' it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the setter implementation doesn't really make any sense considering it will never change the value (it's only function is to initialize). Nonetheless (assuming this would change), if you want to test the value in your setter, you could make it look something like this

```
-(void)setVariableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)variableDictionary {
    NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:20];
    NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:10];
    NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:5];
    _variableDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", b, @"b", x, @"x", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", _variableDictionary);
}
```

This will tell you whether or not the method is even being called. If it's not then you won't get the NSLog message.
This works on my end, if it's not on yours then there is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way, set your property as mentioned below:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong,setter = setTheVariableDictionary:) NSDictionary *variableDictionary;
```

Remove

`-(void)setVariableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)variableDictionary`

and write is as

`-(void)setVariableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)thevariableDictionary`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question. This might help

```
-(void)setVariableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)newVariableDictionary
{
    if (variableDictionary != newVariableDictionary) {
       variableDictionary = newVariableDictionary;
    }
}
```

in your code.

```
-(void)setVariableDictionary:(NSDictionary *)variableDictionary {
```

its normal that it will give you an error when you redeclare your parameter. (NSDictionary *)variableDictionary